# Which test to use?

Tags: variable

I'm trying to figure out which test I would run for a study. Our research question is does the degree of disc extrusion increase with various body positions compared to a supine (lie on their back) position? We will measure the extrusion (in mm) of an intervertebral disc on magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) when the patient is in the supine position and 3 other positions (trunk flexion, extension and rotation). Each subject will have all 4 measurements taken and we're interested in within-subject changes. To me it seems as though there are 4 dependent variables (degree or amount of extrusion at each location) and no independent variables.

Comment: Several terms of your question may not be not clear for CV users e.g.,
MRI or supine.  As far as I understand, you could use a mixed effects
model with both categorical independent variables (patient, position)
and a continuous independent variable (degree of extrusion). The
excursion would be the independent variable. In this setting, you can
compare nested models by likelihood ratio tests (`anova` method in R
terminology).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So there are no dependent variables in the study?

Comment: Sorry, I exchanged 'dependent' and 'independent', maybe because I am used to use response and covariates/predictors.